# private void Methods not work into class Fragment in onCreateView

Tags: android

I have a problem I am trying to make (private void Method)work into my Fragment in ( onCreateView ) but it does not work.

As if I put code directly to onCreateView it's work fine without make it into private void().

Example how its not working :

```
public class classtwst {

    public class Status extends Fragment {
        private List<List_Data> list;
        private RecyclerView rvy;
        private MyAdapter adapter;
         String id;
        private static final String TAG = "Status";
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.status, container, false);
            Intent i = getActivity().getIntent();
            final String id = i.getStringExtra("id");

            rvy=(RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
            rvy.setHasFixedSize(true);
            rvy.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
            list=new ArrayList<>();
            adapter=new MyAdapter(list);

            getComment();//--------Here is the problem

            return rootView;
        }
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        }

        private void  getComment(){
            final String HI ="http://000000000/Cm.php?id=" + id ;
            StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, HI, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("info");
                        for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++ ){
                            JSONObject ob=array.getJSONObject(i);
                            List_Data listData=new List_Data(ob.getString("namelast")
                                    ,ob.getString("contry"));
                            list.add(listData);
                        }
                        rvy.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    }


}
```

How it works:

```
public class classtwst {

    public class Status extends Fragment {
        private List<List_Data> list;
        private RecyclerView rvy;
        private MyAdapter adapter;
         String id;
        private static final String TAG = "Status";
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.status, container, false);
            Intent i = getActivity().getIntent();
            final String id = i.getStringExtra("id");

            rvy=(RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
            rvy.setHasFixedSize(true);
            rvy.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
            list=new ArrayList<>();
            adapter=new MyAdapter(list);

            final String HI ="http://000000000/Cm.php?id=" + id ;
            StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, HI, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("info");
                        for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++ ){
                            JSONObject ob=array.getJSONObject(i);
                            List_Data listData=new List_Data(ob.getString("namelast")
                                    ,ob.getString("contry"));
                            list.add(listData);
                        }
                        rvy.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


            return rootView;
        }
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        }



    }


}
```

So how I can make it work as private void getComment() ?what is the wrong?

Comment: I have tried with the same code. I did not find any issues. What is the error that you are seeing?

Comment: No error but private void  getComment()  not work in onCreateView as Like the first example code

Comment: Does not work means? since its in onCreateView it will get called for sure but are you not getting intended data? what exactly is happening?

Comment: Yes, I do not get data after opening Fragment as Like the first example of code  but as The second example its works well

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass id to `getComment` method to make it work as shown below

in `onCreateView`:

```
getComment(id);
```

and in your method:

```
private void getComment(String id){
//your code
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Glad it helped you. Happy Coding!!